# Access array sent from renderpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

The syntax for renderpage is `@Renderpage("mypage.cshtml", "a", "b")`
where "a" and "b" is an array passed on to the mypage.cshtml I presume.

but how do I access the variables a and b from the mypage.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to WebPageBase.RenderPage method, then you pass an array of data like this:

```
@{ var myObject = new MyObject() // <-- assume MyObject class declared contains properties a&b
      { 
         a = "a",
         b = "b"
      } 
}
<div>
   @RenderPage("mypage.cshtml", myObject)
</div>
```

and then on target page use

```
@model MyObject
```

and access its properties:

```
<div>
   @Model.a 
   @Model.b
</div>
```

**[EDIT]**
MyObject declaration:

```
public class MyObject {
   public string a {  get; set; }
   public string b {  get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an array at all, it's an object with 2 properties...the model would have to be `@model string[]` or `@model IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a,b are some array of type string then below example code may help you

```
List<string> cities =new List<string>{"London","NewYork"}
List<string> shops=new List<string>{"TESCO","Wallmart"}
```

assuming this items are stored in a ViewBag

Shopping.cshtml

```
@model ShopList
{
@RenderPage("Info.cshtml", ViewBag.cities)
}
```

CityInfo.cshtml

```
@model List<string>

@foreach(string city in Model){
<div>
   @city
</div>
}
```

Comment: So, when I add a Razor Web Page to a ASP.NET WebForms, @model doesn't exist in the namespace?